# How can I implement a BFS in a Binary Tree with the following code?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

I've experienced some problems when I try to print the data stored inside the binary tree by BFS(Breadth first search), so, here is my code:

The class BTree is used only for the insertion of the data, allowing the class BTNode to do the recursive process.

```
public class BTree {
BTNode root;

public void insertAtTree(int data){
    if (root == null) root = new BTNode(data);
    else root.insertAtTree(data);
    }
}
```

The class BTNode recursively construct the tree and prints each DFS forms.

```
public class BTNode {
int data;
BTNode right;
BTNode left;

public BTNode(int data){
    this.data = data;
}

public void insertAtTree(int data){
    if (data <= this.data){
        if (left == null) left = new BTNode(data);
        else left.insertAtTree(data);
    }
    else{
        if(right == null) right = new BTNode(data);
        else right.insertAtTree(data);
    }
}

public void printInorden(){
    if (left != null) left.printInorden();
    System.out.print(data+" ");
    if (right != null) right.printInorden();
}

public void printPreorden(){
    System.out.print(data+" ");
    if (left != null) left.printPreorden();
    if (right != null) right.printPreorden();
}

public void printPostorden(){
    if (left != null) left.printPostorden();
    if (right != null) right.printPostorden();
    System.out.print(data+" ");
}
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What happens when you say you "experience some problems?"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for BFS for your Binary Tree.

```
public void funcBFS(BTNode root){

 if (root == null)
   return;

 Queue<BTNode> q = new Queue<BTNode>();
 q.enqueue(root);

 while(!q.isEmpty()){
    BTNode n = q.dequeue();
    System.out.print(n.data+" ");
    if(n.left != null)
       q.enqueue(n.left);
    if(n.right != null)
       q.enqueue(n.right);
 }
}
```